# Wordpress throwing a 404 on a password protected directory outside of WP

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've got a basic WordPress setup, and a separate /portal directory in the root to hold some random private files. Let's say there's /portal/index.html, that is perfectly accessible in browser.  Now I need to password protect /portal.  When I do that through cpanel which creates the /portal/.htaccess file, accessing /portal all of the sudden throws a 404 error.

Any ideas what may be causing this or how to fix?  Thanks!

Comment: "accessing `/portal` all of the sudden throws a 404 error" - Do you mean `/portal/index.html`, or are you literally requesting the directory (and without a trailing slash)? If so, are you expecting a directory listing? Does this work without the pwd-protection? Are you using Apache or LiteSpeed? Please include the contents of both `.htaccess` files: in the root and subdirectory you are protecting.

Comment: Stumbled on this and seems to have done the trick.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270142/htaccess-is-interfering-with-nested-htaccess-htpasswd

The directory is password protected and has several pages/files inside, index.html was just an example.  Accessing any /portal url was causing 404 before applying the fix in that post.  Appreciate your reply, happy holidays!